Gradle problems to refresh dependencies after updating to mac OS Sequoia
My mac just got updated to Sequoia and all the working projects with gradle are having problems*
Even though I have access to internet, it looks like gradle is unable to connect to the maven central repository to download libraries. Here you can see a sample log of the error (It's important to highlight I already confirmed the version and library actually exist properly)
What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl', version: '4.3.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl:org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl.gradle.plugin:4.3.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    MavenLocal

Refresh dependencies of a repository:
./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies

I have similar issue on my M1 Max machine, it looks like a bug in Sequoia. Try to disable firewall in settings.
